# Is it possible to start a conversation with the Bot in MS Teams?

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

Is there any way to start conversation with bot in ms-teams?

I know we can call bot in ms Teams by @botname or graph api.

#### call a bot by @botname

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#receiving-messages

#### call a bot from graph api.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessagemention?view=graph-rest-1.0

But I wanna start conversation from bot like below picture.

[start-conversation from bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhAT8.png)

Do you know how to realize this?

Any advise would be very appreciated, thanks!

===10/26 Add question ====

Thank you for your reply.

> Teams samples for auth, message extension, conversation(message all members in a Team or Channel, '@mention' a user from a bot), file upload and more.

Yes, I know this sample, and I tried to "teams-conversation-bot" by python. But it is call bot only '@mention' a user from a bot or message 1on1.

That means, is it possible to realize below situation using 'send proactive notifications to users.'?

1. Send to http request to bot endpoint by POST from our product.
2. Bot received HTTP request
3. Bot start conversation and '@mention' a channel and a user.

Answer (score 0):

The Bot Framework SDK v4 is delivered as an [open source SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/#readme) on GitHub, targeting .NET, JavaScript, Python, and Java.
Connect a bot to Microsoft Teams, please follow the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Here are the bot builder [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore) for quick-start.

[Teams samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples#teams-samples) for auth, message extension, [conversation](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot)(message all members in a Team or Channel, @mention a user from a bot), file upload and more.

Here to send proactive [notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) to users.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

>Teams samples for auth, message extension, conversation(message all members in a Team or Channel, '@mention' a user from a bot), file upload and more.

Yes, I know this sample, and I tried to "teams-conversation-bot" by python.
But it is call bot only '@mention' a user from a bot or message 1on1.

Comment: That means, is it possible to realize below situation using 'send proactive notifications to users.'?

1. Send to http request to bot endpoint by POST from our product.
2. Bot received HTTP request
3. Bot start conversation  and '@mention' a channel and a user.